# Read properties file located on server from Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a properties file located in my server. Using Javascript or any other client side preferably JQuery, can I load it to fetch values? Is it possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The standard way to access server-side data from client-side Javascript is to pass it out through a controller on the server, preferably encoded in JSON, and use AJAX on the client side to request it from the server. If you don't need any security, you could possibly just expose the static, flat file from the server instead of making a full controller for it, and parse out the contents in Javascript.

There is no way to directly access server-side files since in general client-side code can't access the server's private file system.

Comment: Thanks for the info, I was just wondering after going through this post whether it is possible or not. Can you take a look? Here is the link http://forums.pentaho.com/showthread.php?58384-Reading-Property-File

Comment: Also I am able to access my properties file through webserver, as @asami said. Still can't I have some way on the client side using JS?

Answer (score 2):

If your properties file is accessible through a webserver (for eg: http://your-url/path/to/properties.xml) then  you can simply host a script (http://your-url/path/to/script.html) and fetch the properties file using the AJAX and process it as a XML document (assuming the file is in XML format)

Refer to jQuery documentation on how to parse XML responses and use AJAX Object.

Read this API Doc: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/  it has some examples to give you a head start in fetching documents using AJAX

Comment: I can access my properties file through webserver. Can you show me an example from where i can have a head start, or any link? Thanks

Comment: @Abhishek it doesn't matter if the response is in Json, XML or plain Text. In JS you can parse normal text, read Json objects or traverse XML Documents. You first need to get hold of the Properties file structure.

Comment: Thanks for the link, i'll take a look and get back